# How to make API request to fetch the settings before initializing the webAPI in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am new to C# and .NET.
I have built a simple webAPI app and it will make some **CRUD** operations.
Currently, I have *hard-coded* the `Host address` but actually, I should get this `Host address` from another service.

For this, I want to make a request (another service/app) to fetch some settings (For example. `External host address, Internal host address, and ports...`) before initializing a webAPI app and use the settings in the controllers.

***How can I achieve this?***

Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Startup class -> ConfigureServices.

Comment: Put some code that calls to a service for the service url to use, above the existing code that uses the hardcoded service url? I'm kinda not really understanding the problem.. suppose you read that service url off disk; you'd read it and use it; why would retrieving it from the network be any different ?

Comment: @insane_developer Thanks for your comment. Can you please able to provide any example?

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for your comment. Firstly, I will make it clear.

I am making HTTP request something like 
 ```_client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:1234/comments")``` and it works.

In my case, I have to request ```https://someurl.custom...``` to get the hostUrl (```http://localhost:1234``` ) instead of hard-coding it because the hostUrl will change based on the requirements. I want to use this hostUrl in my controllers.

Comment: The basic idea is, you make the http call in ConfigureServices, save all the configuration you gather in some class, register that instance in the container, and inject it to a controller.